# How to Create a LeftSheet in Android

Tags: android, bottom-sheet

I'm trying to find/create UI component that has all behavior similar to BottomSheetView--those are Peekable, Hideable, Expandable, Dismissable, Swipe Velocity-aware, etc. The only difference to BottomSheetView is that I want it to appear from the LEFT, not BOTTOM.

I've tried using HorizontalScrollView, but its problems are that it takes space even if it's visible, and it doesn't support velocity.

Any suggestion?

Comment: Why not use a drawer layout?

Comment: I don't want to vertically overlap the whole screen.

Comment: Look into slidingpanelayout?

Comment: Thank you. It looks more like what I want.

Comment: Here's an old but helpful tutorial http://blog.sqisland.com/2015/01/partial-slidingpanelayout.html